# How to use log4j and log4j2 properies file to log into same file

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I want to roll and compress log files based on **size** and **time**. I have found out that this can easily be performed with log4j2.
The problem is many internal jars still use log4j for logging, which I want to be logged.

The possible solution I can think of here is by using **log4j1.compatibility=true** by keeping log4j.properties and log4j2.properties

What I can't figure out is how do I use RollingFileAppender in log4j.properties and log4j2 properties?

Please suggest me how can I use both the properties file(log4j and log4j2) to log to the same file with automatic compression when the specific size or time is reached.

**Note:** I tried using **uk.org.simonsite.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender** but getting error **NoClassDefError : org.apache.log4j.xml.unrecognizedelementhandler** due to class is removed in log4j versions greater than v1.2.17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most libraries only use Log4j 1.x to log messages, they don't configure the logging system programmatically. Therefore you can simply replace `log4j` with [`log4j-1.2-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api/2.17.2).

The Log4j 1.x bridge (`log4j-1.2-api`) shares its configuration with Log4j 2.x Core, so you can use a native Log4j 2.x configuration file to configure a `RollingFileAppender`. No `log4j.properties` file or `log4j1.compatibility` property required.

PS: Out of 4 configuration file formats supported by Log4j 2.x (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax)) the properties format is probably the more convoluted. Personally I would choose one of the remaining 3 (XML, JSON or YAML). The XML format does not require additional dependencies.